# Create an app on WP 7 and WP8. Is it possible?

Tags: compatibility

My question is pretty simple: is it possible to create an app working on Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8?

In my web agency, one of my clients need an app working on two different devices. Someone told me we need to develop two different applications, which will cost too many for my client. And I'm pretty sure that apps working on WP7.5 will work on WP8.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is off-topic here. But to answer your question, your WP 7.5 app can run fine on WP7.5 and WP8, but you wont be able to use new development features of WP 8.0/8.1.

But I would recommend you to look at developing seperate apps seperately. If you do follow MVVM pattern, you just need to change the View part ie. the UI code. Rest all of the code can be shared across 7.5, 8.0 and 8.1 app. I have an app which shares most of logic and code files across both the projects (almost 70-80%), mostly the UI code has some minor differences. I'll also recommend creating a specific project for 8.1 which could re-use all of the code from 8.0, and also add specific 8.1 development features.

Ps. In case you are still interested in developing for 7.5 apps, you do need to quickly dev-unlock your 7.5 phone to enable testing on the real device. Check [this link](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-ends-unlocking-windows-phone-7x-devices-developers-dec-31) for more info.

Comment: You don't need two sepearte apps, as every WP7 app works on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Thanks to you too whihathac. I understand that is the right way to develop a good app with full of functionalities, optimized on the right device. But, I've got a quote from an agency and I really don't trust them... :/

Answer (score 1):

You can just write an app for Windows Phone 7.8 and it will work on WP8, no extra work needed. Of course there are some features in the newer versions you can't take advantage of.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Can you tell me more please about these features? Or, could you tell me please if we can access to photo optimizations in the 7.8 version.

Comment: well, define photo optimizations. Of course you can access the pictures library and write some picture enhancement algorithms. You won't be able to use tools like Nokia Imaging SDK though.